# How to share video to Facebook using URL scheme

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I'm trying to enable users to share the most recent video from their Photos gallery to Facebook. I've looked at http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Facebook to see the URL schemes, but I can't figure out the proper URL to create in my app. I have done this successfully for Instagram, here is what it looks like:

```
let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
    fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
    let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithMediaType(.Video, options: fetchOptions)
    if let lastAsset = fetchResult.firstObject as? PHAsset {
        let localIdentifier = lastAsset.localIdentifier
        let u = "instagram://library?LocalIdentifier=" + localIdentifier
        let url = NSURL(string: u)!
        if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url) {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: u)!)
        }

    }
```

What is the proper way to do this successfully?

Comment: There is no supported way

Comment: the app musical.ly does it

Comment: I said no supported way. It may be possible but if the way it not supported it may break at any second

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for clarifying.